# How should I save / load the current user's data from Firestore without blocking the presentation of a new view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Right now, I have a button that presents the current user's profile page (it's a given they're logged in). Unfortunately, I have to make a call to Cloud Firestore in order to load the user's information. I know that I could use Auth.auth().currentUser to try and get information synchronously, but that wouldn't conform properly to the User model I have (which contains things like birthday, username, etc).

I'm confused on how to synchronously display a new view controller which takes in the User model to show the proper data without having to wait behind the Cloud Firestore query to finish.

Should I either save the current user's data in something like UserDefaults / CoreData or should I simply just load the current user's data after the new view controller has been presented and have placeholders for images, text, etc? Worst case seems like I should block the presentation from the button click until after the query finishes, but that seems like a bad solution.

Any help would be much appreciated! This is more of a theoretical question than a specific coding problem, so that's why I didn't include any of my code.

Comment: May want to look into `ObservableObject`s. These are new with SwiftUI (although they can be used on any object). Make your user model observable and then have your controller listen for changes on the user object. This would be the 'load every time' approach.

Comment: I am currently using RxSwift so you’re saying I should wrap my User model as Observable<User> (similar to ObservableObject) and then query for the current user every time and update the fields after it loads?  @Sanzio Angeli

Comment: Making a network call for the logged-in user's information every time they present a view controller, to me, is a definite anti-pattern. I would make one call for the user's information when the app launches and persist that data throughout the life of the app (perhaps in a singleton or a static class; no need to store it on disk unless you're building an offline-capable app).

Comment: As bsod said, just query for the user info once at the start of the app. Then you will have access to this information until the app is closed. The observable part is so that if a viewcontroller is presented before the query has finished, the viewcontroller will still populate once the query finishes.

Comment: Any tips on how to do this with Cloud Firestore? Should I just use their Auth.auth().currentUser object or since I need other information, I should just do my query while loading up the app and store it in a global variable that can then be used in whichever view controllers I need it? @bsod

Comment: Also isn’t that similar to creating a Singleton for the currentUser on the app launch, which is an anti-pattern too? Or am I mistaken? @bsod

Comment: Just query Firestore at app launch and save it somewhere that will live as long as the app is running. Using a singleton for something like this is not what I’d consider an anti-pattern.

Comment: Great, thanks! @bsod

Comment: Since singletons are static by default, how would I load the User object into a singleton to then utilize throughout the app? Or should I use a class that I can pass down and make use of the fact that its pass-by-reference and update the User object with a snapshot listener in case of changes? @bsod

Comment: I would put the snapshot listener inside this object (whatever it is) so it can self update. You can make it a non-static class that you pass by reference if it fits what you're doing. The benefit of making it static is that you can access it anywhere without having to pass it from object to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the implementation I have done based on the comments above. The only issue with this implementation if figuring out how to update a viewModel that takes in a User model in its init (like ViewModel(user: currentUserService.user()) as it won't properly update until that init is called again.

CurrentUserService.swift

```
protocol CurrentUserServicing {
    func user() -> User
}

final class CurrentUserService: CurrentUserServicing {
    
    private var _user: User
    private var listener: ListenerRegistration?
    
    init(user: User) {
        self._user = user
        startSnapshotListener()
    }
    
    deinit {
        stopSnapshotListener()
    }
    
    func user() -> User {
        return _user
    }
    
    private func update(user: User) {
        _user = user
    }
    
    private func startSnapshotListener() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref = db.collection("users").document(_user.id)
        
        listener = ref.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] document, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let document = document, document.exists {
                let result = Result {
                    try document.data(as: User.self)
                }
                
                switch result {
                case .success(let user):
                    if let user = user {
                        self?.update(user: user)
                    }
                case .failure(_):
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func stopSnapshotListener() {
        listener?.remove()
    }
    
}
```

SceneDelegate.swift

```
var appLaunchService: AppLaunchServicing?
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        appLaunchService = AppLaunchService()
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        window?.rootViewController = LaunchViewController()
        
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [unowned self] auth, user in
            if let user = user {
                self.appLaunchService?.loadCurrentUser(id: user.uid)
                    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] user in
                        // If we get the user object, use DI to inject into necessary controllers
                        let currentUserService = CurrentUserService(user: user)
                        self.window?.rootViewController = RootTabBarController(currentUserService: currentUserService)
                    }, onError: { [unowned self] error in
                        // In event of error, force user to log in again
                        self.window?.rootViewController = LandingViewController()
                    })
                    .disposed(by: self.bag)
            } else {
                self.window?.rootViewController = LandingViewController()
            }
        }
        
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```